# Ruby get an outer module's constant from inside a method

Tags: ruby, module, constants

So I have a Ruby method and a constant inside of a module:

```
module Foo
  URL = "http://foo.bar"

  def self.fetch
    # how can I get Foo::URL from in here?
  end
end
```

How do I get `Foo::URL` from inside `Foo.fetch`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to specify the module since you're in the module. Thus,

```
module Foo
  URL = "http://foo.bar"

  def self.fetch
     URL
  end
end
```

Such that,

```
Foo.fetch 
# => "http://foo.bar"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access through Foo::URL. This works for me:

```
module Foo
  URL = "BAR"
  def self.baz
    Foo::URL
  end
end

2.0.0-p195 :025 > Foo.baz
=> "BAR"
```

You should also have access to the bare `URL` from inside the module. What error are you getting when you try to access `Foo::URL`?